# django jquery hide by default

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-selectors, hide

I have made a form with django and made 3 categories.
Now with slideToggle() i can hide or show the part of the form. Now i try to hide the 2nd and 3rd tab by default. and that is where i get stuck.

my django template:

```
<form action="{% url 'item_create' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <ul>
        <li class="title">Basic information</li>
        <li class="fields">
        {% for field in item_form %}
            {% if field.name == "min_level" %}
        </li>
        <li class="title">Requirements</li>
        <li class="fields">
            {% endif %}
            {% if field.name == "strength" %}
        </li>
        <li class="title">Bonus</li>
        <li class="fields">
            {% endif %}
            <p><b>{{ field.label_tag }}</b>{{ field }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

my script:

```
$(function(){
    $('li.fields').filter(":nth-child(3)").hide();  
    $('ul').on('click', 'li.title', function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle(200)
    })
});
```

I am new to javascript and I dont fully understand the "selector" can someone please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:nth-child(3)` will match the third child element. In your case, it won't be very elegant solution, because those children have mixed CSS classes.

Specifically, your filtered elements (with class `fields`) are 2nd, 4th and 6th child, respectively.

Instead, you might want to do [slicing with jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$(function(){
    $('li.fields').slice(1).hide();
    // and then the on-click stuff...
});
```